# "Reverse" of frobenius matrix norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that we have some $m \times n$ matrix $C$, and its full rank (skeleton) decomposition
$$
C = AB^T,
$$
where $A$ is $m\times r$ and $B$ is $n\times r$ for some $r$.

We know that frobenius norm is a matrix norm:
$$
\|C\|_F \leq \|A\|_F\|B\|_F.
$$

But what if I need some "reverse" of that inequality?

Imagine that we know matrix $C$, and we know that $\|A\|_F \approx \|B\|_F$. Can we then find some constant $\alpha$ using matrix $C$ such that
$$
\|C\|_F \geq \alpha \|A\|_F\|B\|_F?
$$

In other words, is there possible to bound norm of $A$ (and $B$, because of our restrictions) for all possible skeleton decompositions by some predefined constant just by scaling down matrix $C$ once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible

For simplicity, just take $r=2$ and the nonzero singular values of $C$ are $1,1$. So that the F norm of C is $\sqrt2$.

Now you may put the nonzero singular values of $A$ as $1/N, N$ and those of $B$ as $N, 1/N$ aligned accordingly

Then $A,B$ have the same F-norm $\sqrt{N^2+1/N^2}$, but $N$ can be as big as you like

Comment: Yeah, a moment ago I came up with this counterexample too. But, even if there has no strict theoretic bound, my problem involves matrix approximation with LogLikelihood cost function instead of quadratic and additional $l_2$ regularization on A and B. So I think that with balanced initialization I can empirically find scale and regularization parameters for which optimization process will maintain low norms in A and B.